# How do I add a Table of Contents

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a document that I'm generating with headers and would like to generate a table of contents but I can't find an example in the documentation of how to insert an AutogeneratedRegion: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_tableofcontents

Could someone give me an example of how to add this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such option yet available in Apps Script to generate table of contents.
You may file a feature request [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request%20from%20user)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm curious though - Why do they have documentation for the class_tableofcontents if you can't instantiate it?