# How to get a link to a part of document (header, paragraph, section...)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm creating a document dynamically with some heading structure

```
doc = DocumentApp.create("My Document");
doc.appendParagraph("Main").setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
var section = doc.appendParagraph("Section 1");
section.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2);
```

I can open it online, insert *Table of contents* and can access directly to "Section 1" by url like:
*https://docs.google.com/document/d/1aA...FQ/edit#heading=h.41bpnx2ug57j*

The question is: How I can get similar url/id  to the "Section 1" in the code at run time and use it later as a link?

If I can't - is there any way to set something like anchor/bookmark and get it's url?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it is impossible to get a document part (section, paragraph, etc) link without having a TOC. Also there is no way to manage bookmarks from a GAS. There is an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=803) on the issue tracker. You can star the issue to promote it.

There is a workaround by using a TOC. The following code shows how to get URL from a TOC. It works only if the TOC exists, if to delete it, the links do not work anymore.

```
function testTOC() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('here is doc id');
  for (var i = 0; i < doc.getNumChildren(); i++) {
    var p = doc.getChild(i);
    if (p.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE_OF_CONTENTS) {
      var toc = p.asTableOfContents();
      for (var ti = 0; ti < toc.getNumChildren(); ti++) {
        var itemToc = toc.getChild(ti).asParagraph().getChild(0).asText();
        var itemText = itemToc.getText();
        var itemUrl = itemToc.getLinkUrl();
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

The function iterates all document parts, finds the 1st TOC, iterates it and the variables `itemText` and `itemUrl` contain a TOC item text and URL. The URLs have `#heading=h.uuj3ymgjhlie` format.

Comment: @yso, indeed a new TOC should be inserted last.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. However when I try to use it I can't get an url to recently created paragraph (with heading).  It looks like TOC need to be updated before.  Unfortunately I can't find any 'toc.update' method in [google manual](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_tableofcontents).  Do you happen to have any other ideas or we just need to wait for google devs to complete the api?

Comment: @yso, how about to add a new TOC after all paragraphs, headers, etc are added. Even if the document already contains a TOC, it's possible to add a new invisible (small font, white-on-white as suggested in the [tracker issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=803))TOC in the document end. If this solution is not suitable, then nothing to do but wait when Google extends the Document Service functionality.

Comment: Well, it wasn't posible [to create TOC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313995/how-do-i-add-a-table-of-contents) in Apps Script two month ago. I've doublechecked it in [document class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_document) - no changes. I guess we need to wait.  Anyway, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Are you able to actually get the URL from `var itemToc = toc.getChild(ti).asParagraph().getChild(0).asText();`? In my tests it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

Starting to test Google Apps in depth, I had issues with the limited features related to the management of table of contents. I bumped into the code you proposed and used it as a starting point to write my own function to format a table of content:
- applying proper headings styles,
- numeroting the different parts.

I hope this would help some of you improving Google Docs templates:

```
/**
* Used to properly format the Table of Content object
*/
function formatToc() {

  //Define variables
  var level1 = 0;
  var level2 = 0;

  // Define custom paragraph styles.
  var style1 = {};
  style1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = DocumentApp.FontFamily.ARIAL;
  style1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 18;
  style1[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
  style1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#ff0000';

  var style2 = {};
  style2[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = DocumentApp.FontFamily.ARIAL;
  style2[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 14;
  style2[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
  style2[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#007cb0';

  // Search document's body for the table of contents (assuming there is one and only one).
  var toc = doc.getBody().findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE_OF_CONTENTS).getElement().asTableOfContents();

  //Loop all the table of contents to apply new formating
  for (var i = 0; i < toc.getNumChildren(); i++) {

    //Search document's body for corresponding paragraph & retrieve heading
    var searchText = toc.getChild(i).getText();
    for (var j=0; j<doc.getBody().getNumChildren(); j++) {
      var par = doc.getBody().getChild(j);
      if (par.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) {
        var searchcomp = par.getText();
        if (par.getText() == searchText) {
          // Found corresponding paragrapg and update headingtype.
          var heading = par.getHeading();
          var level = par.getNestingLevel();
        }
      }
    }

    //Insert Paragraph number before text
    if (level==0) {
      level1++;
      level2=0;
      toc.getChild(i).editAsText().insertText(0,level1+". ");
    }
    if (level==1) {
      level2++;
      toc.getChild(i).editAsText().insertText(0,level1+"."+level2+". ");
    }

    //Apply style corresponding to heading
    if (heading == DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1) {
      toc.getChild(i).setAttributes(style1);
    }
    if (heading == DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2) {
      toc.getChild(i).setAttributes(style2);
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the time the accepted answer was written, the ability to manage bookmarks inside Google Apps Script code was introduced. So it is possible to get a *similar* URL, though not the same exact URL as in example. You can manually insert a bookmark at the section heading, and use that bookmark to link to the section heading. It seems that for the purposes of the question, it will suffice. Here is some sample code (including slight modifications of code from question):

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var body = doc.getBody();
body.appendParagraph("Main").setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
var section = body.appendParagraph("Section 1");
section.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2);

// create and position bookmark
var sectionPos = doc.newPosition(section, 0);
var sectionBookmark = doc.addBookmark(sectionPos);

// add a link to the section heading
var paragraph = body.appendParagraph("");
paragraph.appendText("Now we add a ");
paragraph.appendText("link to the section heading").setLinkUrl('#bookmark=' + sectionBookmark.getId());
paragraph.appendText(".");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it imperative that the document is a native Google docs type (ie. application/vnd.google-apps.document)?

If you stored the document as text/html you would have much greater control over how you assemble the document and how you expose it, eg with anchors.

Comment: Yes you are right. However this document is going to be edited by different people in the future - so it should be google document